# Moving hdd with ESXi to another computer

Tags: vmware-esxi, raid1

I have ESXi with multiple virtual machines on it. My disks are configured as RAID1.
I'd like to move these disks to another computer, and I'd like to know if ESXi  and the virtual machines  would be managed on that new computer as if nothing is changed ?

Comment: What is the RAID controler? What hardware will it be going from/to?

Answer (score 1):

The ESXi version must be the same or newer (to be able to read the vmx and vmdk files), and the RAID must be transferrable, i.e. either use the exact same controller, or softraid.

Some in-guest virtual hardware may misbehave if the offered VM hardware is not a good match, but you can fix that by just editing the VM settings.